# NYC coverage report from outside the project directory

Tags: reactjs, selenium-webdriver, create-react-app, istanbul, nyc

I instrumented a frontend project written using Create React App so that E2E testers could collect coverage reports from their tools (Python using Selenium).

They run their E2E tests on a specific deploy environment where they can interact with a frontend where code is instrumented, they don't have access to the repository, but they can create the `coverage.json` copying the object `window.__coverage__` using Chrome's Developer Tools.

Is there a way for them to use `nyc` against `coverage.json` and create the `html` report *without* having the actual repository cloned on their machines? I can't find a way to achieve this.